# Spring data DbUnit and liquibase for integration test

Tags: spring-data, integration-testing, liquibase, dbunit

I want to write integration test for my spring data repositories but i'm using liquibase to handle the incremental changes on the database. In this [link](https://github.com/mjeanroy/dbunit-plus#liquibase-integration) is necesary use  a changelog from liquibase, but i don't know what happen if there are many changeset inside the changelog file, and what if in the future you add a column to the table, how can i handle this? I cannot find more information about liquibase and DbUnit so I don't know how to use liquibase and DbUnit, Could you give any idea?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Just use Liquibase to set up the DB and DbUnit to insert test data.

Comment: @Jeans Shacuder I edited the question to make it clearer.